# Why hard link doesn't corrupt if we remove the original file?

Tags: linux, rhel, hard-link

Why the hard link doesn't corrupt if we remove the original file?
If I remove the original file then the softlink gets corrupt but hard link doesn't so why it does't corrupt

Comment: hardlinks are like references in programming languages. Deleting a reference does not cause the object to be deleted unless the reference count goes to `0`.

Comment: A dangling symbolic link is not ‘corrupt’. It doesn’t do much that’s useful, but it’s no different from passing a nonexistent path to an application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because hardlinks are essentially references to the same file, and there's no "original" file in terms of hardlinks. They point to same data structure on the disk (the inode that contains next to all metadata of the file).

Whereas softlinks point to filename and not the data structure describing the file.

Comment: actually they point to an `inode` the inode has the list of blocks  and stores other file metadata like timestamps and ownership.

Comment: *They point to same data block on the disk* - That should read "metadata block", as @Jasen pointed out.  Or better, just say inode, because directory entries are just name + inode number.  (Plus file type on some filesystems, so the OS can populate the `d_type` member in readdir results to save programs the trouble of `stat` when looking for subdirectories, for example.)

Comment: Symlinks don't have a concept of "an original file", they point to a _filename_. If that filename goes away, then the link points nowhere, yes, but there's nothing to say the actual _file_ behind the target name has to be the same. E.g. do `echo abc > foo; ln -s foo link; rm foo; echo xyz > foo; cat link`, and you'll see the data from the current `foo` appear, _even though that file didn't exist when the link was created_.

Answer (score 14):

You seem to misunderstand what a *hardlink* and a *file* is in Unix.

The basis of a Unix filesystem are *files*. A *file* is an unstructured *anonymous* bytestream. A file *does not have a name*. It only has a [*file serial number*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_176), basically a unique (for that filesystem) identifier. (The file serial number is sometimes called [*inode*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode))

There are several different kinds of *special files* which are standardized by [POSIX](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX):

- [*device* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) (which are further divided into)

  - [*character* device special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices)
  - [*block* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Block_devices)
- [*FIFO* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) (named pipes)
- [*socket* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)
- [*directory* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing))
- [*symlink* special files](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Operating Systems are allowed to add their own kinds of special files, for example, [Solaris](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)) has [*doors*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing)).

Device files are used to provide an interface to interacting with devices, e.g., traditionally `/dev/sda` to interact with the first hard disk. FIFO special files work like shell pipes, but since they have a name, the two processes reading and writing them can be started at different times and in different security contexts. Sockets allow for interprocess communication similar to a network socket but only on the local machine.

Now we get to the two kinds of special files that are relevant to your question: directories and symlinks.

A directory special file actually works very much like a directory in real-life. For example, think about a phone directory: it lists the names of people together with their phone number. That's exactly what a directory does in a Unix filesystem: it lists the names of files and their file serial number.

This *pairing of name and file serial number* is what we call a [*hardlink* (or just *link*)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link).

When you "delete a file" in Unix using [the `rm` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html), you are *not* actually "deleting the file". You are removing the *entry for that name from the directory*, in other words, you are *removing the hardlink*, not the file. This is called *unlinking* and in fact the POSIX library function used by `rm` is called [`unlink`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html).

So, when you do something like

```sh
touch foo
```

You have *not* created a file named `foo`. You have created a file without a name but with some particular file serial number *and* you have added a directory entry to the current directory which links the name `foo` to the file serial number of the file you just created.

Now, when you use [the `ln` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html) to create a *second* hardlink:

```sh
ln foo bar
```

you have created a *second* directory entry in the current directory which links the name `bar` to the same file serial number that `foo` links to.

It is important to realize that neither of those two links are special. They are exactly the same.

If you now unlink `foo`:

```sh
rm foo
```

All you did was remove the directory entry which links the name `foo` to the file serial number. You did *not* remove the file. Therefore, you can still access the file using the name `bar` since this directory entry was not touched at all.

In fact, you *cannot* delete files in Unix. You can only remove links. The filesystem itself will remove the file once it has no more links pointing to it, and is no longer open.

A *symlink*, however, is a special file which contains a *path*. I.e., when you do

```sh
ln -s /path/to/quux baz
```

You are *literally* writing the string `/path/to/quux` into the file. More precisely, you are creating a symlink special file with the content `/path/to/quux` *and* you are creating a directory entry in the current directory which links the name `baz` with the file serial number of the file you just created.

It doesn't actually matter whether `/path/to/quux` resolved to a file serial number or not. In fact, there are programs which use this for some clever configuration. E.g., the [fnord](https://www.fefe.de/fnord/) and [gatling](https://www.fefe.de/gatling/) web servers use symlinks to represent HTTP redirects, so when you do:

```sh
ln -s https://www.google.com/ /var/www/search.html
```

Then navigating to `http://mydomain/search.html` will redirect you to `https://www.google.com/`.

So, in short:

> Why the hardlink doesn't corrupt if we remove the orginal file?

Because you didn't remove the original file. You only removed one of multiple links. The file is no longer accessible using that specific name, but the file still exists and can still be accessed using other names.

> if i remove the orginal file then the sorflink gets corrupt

Again, you are not removing the original file. You are removing the *name*. But the symlink points to the *name* and not the file. Therefore, the symlink now points to a name that can no longer be resolved to a file.

---

Sidenote: You may have noticed something interesting: directories provide a mapping of names to files. But directories are themselves also files. Therefore, directories automatically also provide a mapping of names to directories.

In other words: directories can be arbitrarily nested in Unix!

This may not sound very exciting today, since every filesystem in widespread use allows for nested hierarchies that are arbitrarily deep. But that was not at all the case when Unix was created almost 60 years ago. Several filesystems at the time either didn't have directories at all or had a fixed level of nesting (e.g. 2 levels).

Making directories special files gives you a hierarchical filesystem for free without having to add any special constructs. This is a very elegant design.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, what uniquely identifies a file filesystem-wide is the `inode` number. This is nothing more that a numeric ID, guaranteed to be unique one the entire filesystem (note: `inodes` can be recycled, but no two "live" files can have the same `inode` in the same filesystem).

A file name is nothing more than a "convenience label" attached to this `inode` inside a specific directory. Hardlinking a file is nothing more then adding *another* such convenient name, inside the same or different directory (in the first case, the new hardlink must have a different name).

You can see the `inode` number via `ls -i`. For example:

```
# ls -alni
total 4
 68329917 drwxr-xr-x.  2 1000 1000   37 Feb  3 15:25 .
101396179 drwx------. 25 1000 1000 4096 Feb  3 15:24 ..
 68329918 -rw-r--r--.  2 1000 1000    0 Feb  3 15:25 test.txt
 68329918 -rw-r--r--.  2 1000 1000    0 Feb  3 15:25 zzz.txt
```

Please note how `zzz.txt` and `test.txt`, having the same `inode` number, really are the *same* file - referenced via two different names. Removing only one of these two names does not really remove (unlink) the `inode` from the filesystem, leaving the other unaffected.

A *soft link* is a completely different thing - it is not a real link to the original `inode`, rather it is a special small file (with its own different `inode`) pointing to the original file *path/name*. Removing the original file leave a broken ("corrupted") pointer behind.

Comment: I know the word was used in the question, but I wouldn't call a dangling symlink "corrupted" in any way. It's still a consistent part of the filesystem structure, and can be `stat()`ed, or `readlink()`ed like any other symlink. Just any access through it will give "file not found" error, but that's the same as any access to a nonexisting name, nothing that would be majorly wrong. And, a new file can be created with the same target name, with no changes required to the symlink.

Comment: @ilkkachu I agree, hence the quotes. A broken symlink remains a consistent file itself.